# How to prevent script vulnerabilities input type in Laravel vue php

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, xss

I'm confused about how to prevent the conversion of data to script type just like the image shown below, Through this it can inject or hack your website, Is there any technique to prevent this? either in laravel or in vuejs, it will very helpful for me, Need help.

I tried putting `$fields = htmlspecialchars($fields);` but it didn't work

[image]
[image]

**Vuejs script**

```
    saveEntry() {
        let formD = new FormData();
        let method = null;
        let putParams = null;

        formD.append("id", this.formFields.id);
        formD.append("name", this.formFields.name);
        formD.append("description", this.formFields.description);

        method = this.create ? "POST" : "PUT";
        putParams = this.create ? "" : "/" + this.formFields.id;

        axios({
            method: method,
            url: BASE_URL + "/transportation/vehicle" + putParams,
            data: formD,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
        });
      }
```

**createVehicle.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Services\TransportationVehicle;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Vehicle;

class CreateVehicle 
{

public function execute($fields, $url)
{

    $user = auth()->user()->id;
    $arr = array('luser' => $user, 'lpage' => 'Office_vehicle' , 'lurl' => $url, 'laction' => 'create');
    $createLogs = createLogs($arr);
    
    $vehicle = Vehicle::create([
        'type' => 1,
        'name' => $fields['name'],
        'description' => $fields['description']

     ]);
    return $vehicle;
   }
 }
```

** Data table list**

```
<script>
  export default {
     data() {
        return {
          create: false,
          edit: false,
          drivers: [],
          formFields: {
            id: "",
            name: "",
            description: "",
          }
       };
     },
   created() {},
   mounted() {
   this.ini();
   },
methods: {
    ini() {
        $(() => {
            this.tdatatable().init();
        });
    },
    tdatatable() {
        var vm = this;
        var initTable = () => {
          var table = $("#vehicle-tbl");
          table.DataTable({
                scrollY: "50vh",
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: BASE_URL + "/transportation/vehicle",
                    type: "GET"
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: "id" },
                    { data: "name" },
                    { data: "description" },
                    { data: "id" }
                ],
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: [1, 4],
                        orderable: false
                    },
                ],

            });
        };
        return {
            init: function() {
                initTable();
            }
        };
    },
}
```

Comment: Your issue would be in how you are showing the data on Vue, show that part (the list).

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks for your response I posted datatable that shows the list

Comment: Oh, I thought you had your own implementation... can you share the official page of that package you are using?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I tried using this and it works it didn't turn to a button but do you prefer to use this?
`$fields = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $fields);` I've been using htmlspecialchars

Comment: I would prefer to see the plugin first, as maybe you can tell it to NOT show the data as `HTML` but you are using a jquery plugin instead of Vue (I am talking about [v-html](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)). So, your solution is good, I think... You can also use [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).